# After starting spring boot secound time getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm getting an ClassNotFoundException when I'm starting my spring boot (via Intellij) application the secound time. So the first time every thing is working fine and after then the exception occurs.

The exception: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release. Error: Could not find or load main class com.demo.demo.DemoApplication Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.demo.DemoApplication`

Using Java 15 and gradle for my Demo project.

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
id 'java'}
group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'


  }
}
```

DemoApplication Java file

```
package com.demo.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DemoController my test Controller

```
package com.demo.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add import statements in classes you have posted

Comment: yes sure and done

Comment: does this issue persists, if you use gradle bootRun consecutively ?

Comment: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'mainClass'.
   > Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved